For IncludePoints in ElementToMesh, how do I include a Sphere?
This may be dumb, but I'm using this solution Boundary conditions being ignored or not obeyed by NDSolveValue to include in this PDE a boundary condition on a sphere inside the ball.
\[CapitalOmega]3D = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10];
parameters = {k -> 4};
bc = Hold[DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, True]];
nc = NeumannValue[
   u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]3D, 
   "IncludePoints" -> Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.]];

pde = {DiffusionReactionModel[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, k, "NoFlow", 
      "NoSource"] == nc, ReleaseHold[bc]} /. parameters;
ufun = NDSolveValue[pde, u, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];

where I shamelessly copied and edited code from the wolfram website
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ClearAll[DiffusionReactionModel]
DiffusionReactionModel[T_, X_List, k_, Velocity_, Source_] := 
 Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, Velocity . Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a . Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]

Doing so yields me a (*ToElementMesh: -- Message not found -- (Sphere[{0,0,0},1])*).
Does anyone know the proper way of including a set of points (which cannot be typed in by hand explicitly) in ToElementMesh? Or should I include the Neumann Condition differently here?
EDIT: I tried to include the points explicitly via
additionalpoints = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Flatten[Table[{Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
      Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi, 
      Pi/25}, {\[Phi], 0, 2  \[Pi], \[Pi]/25}], 1]];

nc = NeumannValue[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] additionalpoints];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]3D, 
   "IncludePoints" -> additionalpoints];

as is given on the documentation for another example. However when I plot the mesh
mesh["Wireframe"]
ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]3D]["Wireframe"]

and compare to one without these additional points, nothing changes. This also produces another strange error when executing the whole code at the beginning with the aforementioned modifications:
(*CompiledFunction: Argument (<<912... bytes>> at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor or machine sized integers)*) The error is caused by NDSolve
EDIT2: The original plan was to solve on the whole \[CapitalOmega]3D while imposing the Neumann conditions on the sphere I specified, which is the boundary of the inner Ball of user21's answer. A hollow ball is fine too, since I am more interested in the solution outside of the inner ball, but shouldn't it be possible to have two different materials and impose Neumann conditions on the inner ball while also solving for the field on both outside and inside the inner ball?

Can you clarify a bit what you want to do. Do you have a Ball with a hole inside and you want the NeumannValue on that inner boundary. Or do you have a ball made up of two different materials?

@user21 I have edited my question accordingly

Assuming you want a hollow Ball and the NeumannValue on the inside you can use:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ClearAll[DiffusionReactionModel]
DiffusionReactionModel[T_, X_List, k_, Velocity_, Source_] := 
 Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 0, Velocity . Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a . Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]

\[CapitalOmega]3D = 
  RegionDifference[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10], Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]];
parameters = {k -> 4};
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]3D, 
   "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0, 0}}];
mesh["Wireframe"]


Note, that the original DirichletCondition will apply on any boundary condition and overwrite everything else - even a possibly wanted internal boundary - very unlikely that you want this.
(*bc=DirichletCondition[u[x,y,z]==1,True];*)
bc = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 1, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 10];
nc = NeumannValue[u[x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1];
pde = {DiffusionReactionModel[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, k, "NoFlow", 
     "NoSource"] == nc, bc} /. parameters

A Plot:
Plot[ufun[x, 0, 0], {x, 1, 10}]



Could you clarify which way the inner sphere is oriented? It seems to me as if the normal vector points to the origin of the inner sphere.

Sorry for bothering so much, but I also encounter a weird behaviour if I vary the radius of the inner ball. For 1 to 3 (I changed the sign in the NeumannValue to -u), the solution decays when approaching the inner sphere, as I expect. But suddenly for 4, I get a constant solution, which seems very weird to me. Any higher and I get a warning about the quality of the mesh (below 0).
